# When I alert "this" on mouse-over, over a <td> [Object Window] pops up - what is that?

Tags: javascript

I have several tables on my page, and I want to find out the value of a table cell when I mouse over it.

I've tried `alert(this);` with a "mouseenter" handler, and sure enough I get an alert when mousing over a `<td>`, but the alert says [object Window].

Anyone know what object Window means? Or how I should set about getting the value (ie the innerText) of a `<td>` when I mouseover it?

Thanks in advance!

*Edit

By popular demand, here is the code:

```
<tr onmouseover ='showDetails()'><td class = 'actuCourse'></td></tr>
```

then

```
function showDetails(){

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".actuCourse").mouseenter(function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});

}
```

this is what I have now thanks to one of the answers that suggested jQuery

it works, but alerts successively more alerts each time I mouseover.

Thanks again

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Let us see the code you're using - if `this` doesn't know what it's referring to it defaults to the `window` object. I suspect your use of it is incorrect

Comment: I agree with the preceding two comments, show us the code. I tested this with `$('td').mouseenter(function() {alert(this)});` and I get `HTMLTableCellElement`. Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: You don't want the document ready wrapper in that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is every time the `tr` is hovered, an additional `mouseenter` listener is added to the `actuCourse` element.

it should be

```
<tr><td class = 'actuCourse'></td></tr>
```

And

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".actuCourse").mouseenter(function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

If the `td` or the class  is added dynamically, then use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('mouseenter', ".actuCourse", function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: i took a leaf from this and what SmokeyPHP said.

I removed the onmouseenter from the `<tr>` as you said, but then the $(document).ready... wouldn't execute since, as you guessed, they get added dynamically.

So I added a `"onClick = showDetails()"` where the tables get generated, and now I have just

`$(".actuCourse").mouseenter(function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    });`

as smokey recommended, and all works well.

thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/mbyp8/ This works using jquery. Basically you do `alert($(this).text());`

Comment: this works well when I mouseover the first time. Every subsequent time it alerts one extra time, no matter which <td> I mouse over. This is the code I'm using:

$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".actuCourse").mouseenter(function(){
  alert($(this).text());
 });
});

which is in a function that gets executed on a <td>'s mouseover